# Netty WebSocket Client Delays in channel.writeAndFlush

Tags: websocket, netty

We have a WebSocket client application built using Netty 4.1.50. The application is running on a Linux VM/Container.

Here is the code snippet

```
EventLoop = new EpollEventLoopGroup(0, new DefaultThreadFactory("websocket-client");
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
                  .channel(EpollSocketChannel.class)
                  .handler(channelInitializer)
                  .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

ChannelFuture cf = bootstrap.connect(configuration.getHost(), configuration.getPort());
channel = cf.channel();

          /*
           * Wait for it to complete, or throw a fault.
           */
          try {
              cf.sync();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              logger.warn("Failed to connect: ", e);
              return;
          }

          logger.debug("Socket channel {} got created", channel);
          cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();
          logger.info("Connection closed");

logger.debug("Writing data to socket channel {}", channel);
String messageText = JsonUtil.toJson(transportMessage);
ChannelFuture channelFuture = channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(messageText));
channelFuture.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
logger.debug("Data written to socket channel. Request id: {}", transportMessage.getRequestId());
              });
```

We are doing lot load testing by sending a lot of messages over the WebSocket channel from the Server and under the load, we are observing delays in writing the message to WebSocket channel on the client-side.

## Logs

```
DEBUG 06/22 09:12:13.246 com.test.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 {X-REQUEST-ID=102953b0-772e-4187-947d-c129fa099291} Writing data to socket channel [id: 0xd63b3752]
DEBUG 06/22 09:12:13.378 com.test.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: websocket-client-1-1 {} Data written to socket channel. Request id: 102953b0-772e-4187-947d-c129fa099291

DEBUG 06/22 09:12:36.966 com.test.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 {X-REQUEST-ID=34568e89-95ff-4be3-abcf-ac2edd315f31} Writing data to socket channel [id: 0xd63b3752]
DEBUG 06/22 09:13:07.392 com.test.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: websocket-client-1-1 {} Data written to socket channel. Request id: 34568e89-95ff-4be3-abcf-ac2edd315f31

DEBUG 06/22 09:15:06.449 com.test.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: I/O dispatcher 2 {X-REQUEST-ID=0e28fbae-4c06-4551-9a73-8c171cc09911} Writing data to socket channel [id: 0xd63b3752]
DEBUG 06/22 09:15:06.449 com.vmware.hcs.broker.connector.client.websocket.WebSocketConnectionManagerImpl: websocket-client-1-1 {} Data written to socket channel. Request id: 0e28fbae-4c06-4551-9a73-8c171cc09911
```

for request-id '34568e89-95ff-4be3-abcf-ac2edd315f31', it took ~30 sec to write into SOCKET channel.

Comment: Where do you call `connect(...)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I updated the code to include connect() method.

Comment: Can you also log if the write was successful or not ?